# Daily Outlook macro to poll working from office or home

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to create an automated mail prompt (radio msgbox?) to poll users if they are working from home or office every day at 9am and send the response to me , also collect daily information in an excel at the end of day.
I understand something like this is possible in Excel VBA using **ontime** but it doesn't work for outlook macros.

Can a user input be given with a recurring appointment/meeting

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A possible scenario is to use the [MailItem.VotingOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.votingoptions) property which returns or sets a string specifying a delimited string containing the voting options for the mail message. Then you can read the [MailItem.VotingResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.votingresponse) property which returns or sets a string specifying the voting response for the mail message. This property is usually set to one of the delimited values returned by the `VotingOptions` property on a reply to the original message. But no such properties provided in the OOM for appointment items.

Any scripts in the message body will be blocked by Outlook automatically for security reasons.